# Can diagonalization mod p be generalized to diagonalization mod n?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, diagonalization

When you diagonalize a matrix $A$, your $D$ matrix will be the similar to if you diagonalized $A$ mod $p$ (but $D$ will also be mod $p$ in this scenario). I'm having a brainfart moment here. Does $p$ have to be prime for this to matter? Or can this be generalized to any integer $n$? For example, if I have $A$ mod $n$, will $D$ just be $D$ mod $n$? Or is something lost in translation if you don't have a prime modulus?

Comment: $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&3\end{pmatrix}\in GL_2(\mathbb Q)$ can be diagonalized to $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&3\end{pmatrix}\in GL_2(\mathbb Q)$, but $A\bmod 2=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\in GL_2(\mathbb F_2)$ cannot be diagonalized

Comment: I don't think I understand... $2$ is still a prime number, so how does this generalize to $n$?

Comment: The problem is that if you write $A = PDP^{-1}$ in say $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ with $A,D,P \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, then you won't necessarily have $P$ invertible mod $p$.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that not even for prime modulus it is clear that a rationally diagonalizable matrix is diagonalizable in the first place.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Is this due to the reciprocity / invertibility of $\mathbb{Z}_p$? Can you think of a diagonalizable matrix $A$ that is diagonalizable in mod $p$ (say 2 or 3 or something simple) but not in mod $n \neq p$ (like 4)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is in the dirction you want: Assume you have  $p,q$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$, matrices $P,D,P'\in Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ and $Q,E,Q'\in Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)$, $A\in Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb Z)$ such that $PP'=1$, $QQ'=1$, $PDP'\equiv A\pmod p$, $QEQ'\equiv A\pmod q$.
Then you can find (using the Chinese remainder theorem), $R,F,R'\in Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb Z/pq\mathbb Z)$ such that $R\equiv P\pmod p$, $R\equiv Q\pmod q$, $F\equiv D\pmod p$, $F\equiv E\pmod q$, $R'\equiv P'\pmod p$, $R'\equiv Q'\pmod q$. Then $RR'\equiv 1\pmod p$ and $RR'\equiv 1\pmod q$, hence $RR'\equiv 1\pmod{pq}$, and also $RFR'\equiv A\pmod p$ and $RFR'\equiv A\pmod q$, hence $RFR'\equiv A\pmod{pq}$.